# Evaluation of formal series

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, generating-functions

Is it possible to get a closed form for coefficients of $$\left(1+\frac{2t}{(1-t)^2}\right)^{-n}$$ there $n$ - positive integer?

It's easy to obtain the formula for $m$-th coefficient as $$\binom{n}{1}\binom{m}{m-1}(-2)+\binom{n+1}{2}\binom{m+1}{m-2}(-2)^2+\dots$$ but I can't simplify it further.

Comment: @Semiclassical Sure, I forgot to restrict $m$ to be positive, but in this assumption formula seems true.

Comment: Rechecked things, and I'm withdrawing my objection. (The only reason the $m=0$ case is odd is b/c technically there's also a term $\binom{n-1}{0}\binom{m-1}{m}$ at the start, which gives $1$ if $m=0$ but vanishes otherwise.)

Answer (score 1):

An idea to make, possibly, things easier:

You can make some algebraic simplifications. Choose to develop whatever you like better:

$$\left(1+\frac{2t}{(1-t)^2}\right)^{-n}=\left(\frac{(1-t)^2}{1+t^2}\right)^n=\left(1-\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(-1)^k\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)^k$$